# jQuery Mobile - Chrome stuck loading

Tags: html, google-chrome, jquery-mobile

I started to learn jQuery Mobile.
I created basic website which is working fine in Firefox.
However, it's not working in Google Chrome. It is stuck in "loading".
How I can fix this issue? I use latest stable Firefox and Chrome.

http://s12.postimg.org/mfdcx8mu5/chrome.png

Source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
Content of the document......
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: show us the "Content of document..." markup and script

Comment: There is nothing, it is only "text"... I took it from here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp Only "custom part" is jQuery mobile script...

Comment: Here is your exact code in jsBin: https://jsbin.com/kojama/edit?html,output  It runs fine in Google Chrome for me.  Can you make it reproduce your issue?

Comment: Mmh... Odd, when I open jsBin link using Chrome it works fine. 
However, if I open index.html file it stuck "loading".
I have default chrome installation, so I don't have any add-ons etc..
Can you try create index.html file using that source code and test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when you try to open local html files by "file:///..." interface. Once you upload your html file to any http server the issue is gone.